# How to load custom icon into 2d gizmo in Blender?

Tags: scripting, add-on, gizmo

I would like to load custom icon for a button displayed on 3d View (GIZMO_GT_button_2d) in my add-on.

Looks like "icon_value" way does't work here - it works only in panels.
Is there any other way get this working?

Comment: Did you ever figure it out?

Comment: Unfortunately it is not possible at the moment.
Best approach would be to help pushing the fix that has been submitted but never merged. It is here: https://projects.blender.org/blender/blender/pulls/108988

Comment: It looks like there was some kind of conflict with the target branch so they never merged it. I would really love to be able to have custom icons on the 2D Gizmos. It seems to be quite a limitation since the default set of icons that comes with Blender isn't that big and specific. I did leave a comment at the suggested link provided by @Werwack, hopefully something can be done. If anyone knows of any solution/workaround please let us know. Thanks!